# Javascript - replace multiple html elements with new chars in a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to find and replace html tags and replace them all with different characters in a single function.

The aim is to create a function to do a multiple find and replace on a large block of text. I'm trying with a small block first but seem to be having difficulty with replacing some of the tags

```
    const paragraph = '<p>I think Ruth's dog <a href="test-link/">is</a> cuter than your dog! 
    </p>';

    console.log(paragraph.replaceAll('<a href="', '<a href=\"{{store}}'));
    console.log(paragraph.replaceAll('/">', '\/\">'));
    console.log(paragraph.replaceAll('</p>', '<\/p>'));
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this properly that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The double braces suggest you are working with some templating framework. Please clarify.

Comment: Expected output is: <p>I think Ruth's dog <a href=\"{{store}}test-link\/\">is<\/a> cuter than your dog! <\/p>

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite easy to write some code to transform your input into your desired output, but I'm not sure how much that would help you.

Rather, what would be better would be to identify the rules of what you are attempting to do. This is what I've understood so far (pls correct me if I am wrong):

- Closing tags need their slash escaping, i.e. `</a>` becomes `<\/a>` and `</p>` becomes `<\/p>`
- Slashes inside the `href` value are escaped, i.e. `<a href="test-link/">is</a>` becomes `<a href="test-link\/">is</a>`
- Quotes surrounding the `href` value are escaped, i.e. `<a href="test-link/">is</a>` becomes `<a href=\"test-link/\">is</a>`
- The `href` value is prepended with `{{store}}`, i.e. `<a href="test-link/">is</a>` becomes `<a href="{{store}}test-link/">is</a>`

To that end, I have made a quick change to your test paragraph by including it in backticks (as opposed to single quotes), as it already contains a single quote which would cause everything to break. Either that or you escape the single quote.

Anyway, this is our test input:

```
const html = `
  <p>I think Ruth's dog <a href="test-link/">is</a> cuter than your dog!</p>
`;
```

Run the following code against this:

```
const updatedHtml = html
  .replace(/<\/(\w+)>/g, '<\\/$1>')
  .replace(/<a href="([^"]+)">/g, (match, p1) => `<a href="${p1.replace(/\//g, '\\/')}">`)
  .replace(/<a href="(.+?)">/g, '<a href=\\"{{store}}$1\\">');

console.log(updatedHtml);
```

And we get your desired output:

```
<p>I think Ruth's dog <a href=\"{{store}}test-link\/\">is<\/a> cuter than your dog!<\/p>
```

And for testing purposes, let's expand the HTML code:

```
const html = `
  <p>I think Ruth's dog <a href="test-link/">is</a> cuter than your dog!</p>
  <div><p>I <em>think</em> Ruth's dog <a href="one/two/three/">is</a> cuter than your dog!</p></div>
`;
```

Gives us:

```
<p>I think Ruth's dog <a href=\"{{store}}test-link\/\">is<\/a> cuter than your dog!<\/p>
<div><p>I <em>think<\/em> Ruth's dog <a href=\"{{store}}one\/two\/three\/\">is<\/a> cuter than your dog!<\/p><\/div>
```

Which is also hopefully conformant to your rules.

Parsing HTML with regex is an [infamously tricky process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1136887), so my advice would be to use regex to get you most of the way there, then check the last 10% manually.